# How can I find all files in a folder that contain a match of a regular expression in the file name?

Tags: files, regular-expression, filenames, search

I'd like to find all of the files in my home folder on Linux (Ubuntu, in this case) that contain a match a particular regular expression. Is there a simple Unix command that I can use in order to do this?

For example, I'd like to find all of the files in my home folder with names that contain a match of the following regex (here, using Javascript-style notation): `((R|r)eading(T|t)est(D|d)ata)`

Comment: Are you looking for files whose content matches a regexp (from your post body), or files whose name matches a regexp (from your post title)?

Comment: I meant files whose name matches a regexp.

Comment: in that case, it's just: `ls -l *[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata*`

Comment: I entered the above command on Ubuntu and got the following output: `ls: cannot access *[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata*: No such file or directory` even though there is a file on my system that matches the regex.

Comment: I tried entering `ls -l *.js*` and got the same output:  `No such file or directory`. I expected to see a list of every file that ended in .js, but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Find's `-name` option supports file globbing.  It also supports a limited set of regex-like options like limited square-bracket expressions, but for actual regex matches, use `-regex`.

If you're looking for a match in the *contents* of a file, use `grep -r` as Craig suggested.

If you want to match the filename, then use `find` with its `-regex` option:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata.*' -print
```

Note the shift in regex, because `find` doesn't portably support bracketed atoms in its regex.  If you happen to be on a Linux system, GNU find supports a `-regextype` option that gives you more control:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*((R|r)eading(T|t)est(D|d)ata).*' -print
```

Note that if all you're looking for is case matching, `-iregex` or even `-iname` may be sufficient.  If you're using `bash` as your shell, Gilles' globstar solution should work too.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` has a recursive `-r` option, which will search every file in every subdirectory for the pattern.

The `-l` option just lists the files containing the pattern.  If you want a count of matches in each file, use `-c` instead, and if you want to see the matches, don't use either -l or -c.

1. `(R|r)` is just a verbose way of writing `[Rr]`.  it's also slower than a class (but not enough to matter unless it's in a loop that runs millions of times):

   `grep -lr '[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata' ~/`
2. Completely case-insensitive:

   `grep -lir 'readingtestdata' ~/`
3. if you just want to search files in ~ but not in subdirectories then you can use `find`:

   `find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0r grep -l '[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata'`

Comment: Instead of `xargs` you can use `find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -l '[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata' {} \+`.

Comment: yes, you can...but I like xargs.  find's -exec always seems to suffer from annoying shell-quoting/escaping problems. This is tedious and tends to make things harder to read.

Comment: @CraigSanders It's the other way round! There's never any quoting problem with `find -exec`, but using `xargs` with `find` only works with “tame” file names or with `-print0`/`-0`.

Comment: If you want to search files in `~` but not in subdirectories, don't use `find`! It's just `grep -l '[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata' *`.

Comment: yes, if you don't mind ignoring dot-files (most wouldn't care).  also, there's a very small chance that '*' may expand to exceed the command-line length limit.  Finally, xargs can be run with -P to run multiple greps in parallel.

Comment: re: quoting issues.  your experience must differ from mine.  `find -exec` always gives me problems with shell quoting and escaping, `xargs` never does.  i'm talking about the command itself, not the data in the pipe.

Comment: Note that the question has been clarified, Anderson is in fact looking for files whose name matches the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Shells have [wildcard characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globbing) that differ from the usual regexp syntaxes: `?` to match any single character, `*` to match any number of characters, and `[abc]` to match any single character among `a`, `b` or `c`. The following command shows all files whose name matches the extended regular expression¹ `((R|r)eading(T|t)est(D|d)ata)` in the current directory:

```
echo *[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata*
```

If you want to find files in subdirectories as well, then first run `shopt -s globstar` (you can put this command in your `~/.bashrc`). This turns on the `**` pattern to match any level of subdirectories:

```
echo **/*[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata*
```

Shell wildcard characters are not as powerful as regular expressions. For example, there is no or (`|`) operator. You can get the power of regular expressions, but with a different syntax for historical reasons. Add `shopt -s exgblob` to your `.bashrc`, then you can use `@(foo|bar)` to match `foo` or `bar` (like `foo|bar` in an ERE), `*(pattern)` to match a sequence any number of occurrences of `pattern` (like `(pattern)*` in an ERE), `+(pattern)` to match one or more occurrences, `?(pattern)` to match zero or one occurrence, and `!(pattern)` to match anything except `pattern` (no ERE equivalent).

¹  <sub>“Extended regular expression” (ERE for short) is the unix name of the regex syntax that JavaScript uses.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass your pattern to find:

```
$ find . -type f  -name "[Rr]eading[Tt]est[Dd]ata*"
```

For the specific pattern in the question, you can simply use case insensitive find:

```
$ find . -type f -iname readingtestdata
```

Comment: **-1**  The `-name` option support a limited number of extensions to file globbing.  Its square bracket expressions work in a way that is similar to regexes, but `-name` does *not* support full regexes.

Comment: @ghoti, I never said it did. The code above **works**. Its input _is_ a regular expression. It is not an ERE, but even "*a" is essentially a regular expression. According to the [Single Unix Specification Version 2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html#tag_007_003), even a single character is a Basic Regular Expression matching itself.

Comment: You said "The find command can take a regular expression as input", then you provided an example where find is interpreting a file glob.  The fact that globbing use some similar notation to regular expressions is immaterial.  The above string is *not* a regular expression unless it is interpreted using find's `-regex` option.

Comment: @ghoti, I made this into a [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46436/what-isthe-definition-of-a-regular-expression), come convince me there :).

Comment: @ghoti, I also removed any mention of regex to avoid confusion.