# Why does [a-z] asterisk match numbers?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, wildcards

I have 3 directories at current path.

```
$ls
a_0db_data  a_clean_0db_data  a_clean_data
$ls a_*_data
a_0db_data:

a_clean_0db_data:

a_clean_data:

$ls a_[a-z]*_data
a_clean_0db_data:

a_clean_data:
```

I expected last ls command to match only `a_clean_data`. Why did it also match the one containing `0`?

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46436/22222) for more on the difference between a regular expression and a glob.

Comment: So the fact that `a_*_data` matched` any of this files didn't surprise you?

Comment: @Cthulhu you got me!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `[a-z]` part isn't what matches the number; it's the `*`. You may be confusing shell [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and [regular expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/RegularExpression).

Tools like `grep` accept various flavours of regexes ([basic](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) by default, `-E` for extended, `-P` for [Perl regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions))

E.g. (`-v` inverts the match)

```
$ ls a_[a-z]*_data | grep -v "[0-9]"
a_clean_data
```

If you want to use a bash regex, here is an example on how to test if the variable `$ref` is an integer:

```
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $ref =~ $re ]] ; then
  echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: How to use bash regex then? (see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html)

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345936/regular-expression-usage-with-ls)

Answer (score 21):

So the problem is: why does `a_[a-z]*_data` match `a_clean_0db_data`?

This can be broken down into **four** parts:

- `a_` matches the beginning of `a_clean_0db_data`, leaving `clean_0db_data` to be matched
- `[a-z]` matches any character in the range `a-z` (e.g. `c`), leaving `lean_0db_data` to be matched
- `*` matches any number of characters, e.g. `lean_0db`
- `_data` matches the trailing `_data`

In regular expressions, `[a-z]*` would mean *any number of characters (including zero) in the range of a..z*, but you are dealing with shell globbing, not with regular expressions.

If you want regular expressions, a few `find` implementations have a `-regex` predicate for that:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex "^.*/a_[a-z]*_data$"
```

The `-maxdepth` is only here to limit the search-results to the folder you are in.
The *regular expression* matches the *entire* filename, therefore I have added a `^.*/` to match the path-portion

Answer (score 11):

`*` in shell patterns matches 0 or more characters. It's not to be confused with the `*` regular expression operator that means *0 or more of the preceding atom*.

There is no equivalent of regexp `*` in basic shell patterns. However, various shells have extensions for that.

- `ksh` has `*(something)`:

  ```
  ls a_*([a-z])_data
  ```
- you can have the same in `bash` with `shopt -s extglob` or `zsh` with `setopt kshglob`:

  ```
  shopt -s extglob
  ls a_*([a-z])_data
  ```
- In `zsh` with `extendedglob` enabled, `#` is equivalent to regexp `*`:

  ```
  setopt extendedglob
  ls a_[a-z]#_data
  ```
- In recent versions of `ksh93`, you can also use regular expressions in globs. Here with *extended* regular expressions:

  ```
  ls ~(E:a_[a-z]*_data)
  ```

Note that `[a-z]` matches different things depending on the current locale. It generally matches only the 26 `a` to `z` latin non-accented letters in the `C` locale. In other locales, it generally matches more, and doesn't always make sense. To match a letter in your locale, you may prefer `[[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: Could you give an example of `[a-z]` matching more that the 26 letters matched in the C locale?  What I remember from when I last looked at this, all encodings practically used in Unix variants had ISO-646 as a base (then the upper 128 codes where used differently, directly for characters in encodings like the ISO-8859-X, combined in encodings like UTF-8 or the EUC family). Even AIX hadn't EBCDIC locales (at least as available to me). I remember trying to find if POSIX/UNIX standards demanded it, but I don't remember the result.

Comment: @AProgrammer, that's independent of the encoding, that's based on sort order (LC_COLLATE). `[a-z]` generally includes `é` or `í` (but not necessarily `ź`) in the the locales where the charset have them, whether the codepoint in that encoding is between that of a and z or not. Only the C locale guarantees a sort order based on codepoint value. See [this other answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/22565) for more details.

Comment: Ok, what I missed was that the range was interpreted according to the current collation sequence.