# Why does '[a-z]*' match non-alphabetical strings?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file `alphanum` with these two lines:

```
123 abc
this is a line
```

I am confused as to why, when I run `sed 's/[a-z]*/SUB/' alphanum`, I get the following output:

```
SUB123 abc
SUB is a line
```

I was expecting:

```
123 SUB
SUB is a line
```

I found a fix (use `sed 's/[a-z][a-z]*/SUB/'` instead), but I don't understand why it works and mine doesn't.

Can you help?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154747/why-does-a-z-asterisk-match-numbers

Comment: @Kamaraj, that one is similar, but has the shell patterns vs regexes confusion on top (and the answers concentrate on the former, since that's what the `ls foo*` there uses). But anyway, if you find questions that are duplicates, I think you should be able to flag them as such, too.

Comment: check out http://regexr.com for live visuals & explains

Comment: @RozzA Note that the website that you link to supports Javascript and Perl regular expressions, not POSIX regular expressions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The pattern `[a-z]*` matches *zero* or more characters in the range `a` to `z` (the *actual* characters are dependent on the current locale).  There are zero such characters at the very start of the string `123 abc` (i.e. the pattern matches), and also four of them at the start of `this is a line`.

If you need at least *one* match, then use `[a-z][a-z]*` or `[a-z]\{1,\}`, or enable extended regular expressions with `sed -E` and use `[a-z]+`.

To visualize where the pattern matches, add parentheses around each match:

```
$ sed 's/[a-z]*/(&)/' file
()123 abc
(this) is a line
```

Or, to see all matches on the lines:

```
$ sed 's/[a-z]*/(&)/g' file
()1()2()3() (abc)
(this) (is) (a) (line)
```

Compare that last result with

```
$ sed -E 's/[a-z]+/(&)/g' file
123 (abc)
(this) (is) (a) (line)
```

Comment: Technically `[a-z]` matches _collating elements_ which can be made of more than one character. For instance, in some Hungarian locales, `[a-z]` matches on `dzs`

Answer (score 12):

Because `*` matches *zero or more* repetitions of the previous atom, and all regex engines try to find the first match. There's a substring of exactly zero letters in the start of your string, so that's where it matches. In the case where the string starts with a letter, the `*` matches as many as it can, but this is secondary to finding the leftmost match.

Zero-length matches can be a bit problematic, and as you saw, the solution is to modify the pattern so that it requires at least one character. With extended regexes, you could `+` for that: `sed -E 's/[a-z]+/SUB/'`

For fun, try:

```
echo 'less than 123 words' | sed 's/[0-9]*/x/g'
```