# Using rename to remove '.orig' from file and add '_1' to basename

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find, rename

I'm using a script to make backups of files, and to avoid overwriting files I've used `cp --backup`. Which leaves me with a number of files that look like `example.mov.orig` and `test.mov.orig`. I cannot figure out regular expressions at all, and was wondering if anyone knows of a way to cut off the `.orig` and append `_1` to the base name using rename.

Essentially the result I'm looking for is command that would change `example.mov.orig` to become `example_1.mov` that I could use in conjunction with `find /example/ -name *.*.orig`

Output from `rename --version` is `util-linux-ng 2.18`

Comment: What distribution are you using? There are two common `rename` implementations out there and they have very different format. We need to know which one you have to answer correctly.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm using Puppy Linux

Comment: That should be perl-rename then. OK, please [edit] your question and post the output of `rename.ul --version`. That will either priutn a usage message (which includes the information we need) or version information. Either way, please add the output to your question.

Comment: @terdon, ITYM `rename --version`.  `rename.ul` is always going to be the util-linux rename, and `prename` is always going to be the perl rename.  `rename` could be either.  on a debian-based system, it's controlled by the alternatives system - `update-alternatives --display rename`

Comment: @cas Debian-based systems default to `prename`, yes, but as I recall, the RedHat world defaults to `rename.ul`. I don't know if all distros will have both installed by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rename` command you need is:

- If you're using `rename` from `util-linux`:

  ```
  rename . _1. *.orig && rename .orig '' *.orig
  ```

  The first will replace the first occurence of `.` with `_1.` for all files ending in `.orig`. The second will remove the `.orig` from the file names.
- If you're using perl-rename (default on Debian-based systems), things are simpler since it uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions so can do everything in one step:

  ```
  rename 's/(\..*)\.orig/_1$1/' *orig
  ```

  Since this version uses The regex will match the first `.` (`\.`, the `.` needs to be escaped since ti means "any character" whan not escaped), then everything (`.*`) until `.orig`. Because the first pattern is inside parentheses, it is "captured" and can later be referred to as `$1`. Therefore, the replacement will replace anything matched previously with a `_1` and the captured pattern (the first extension) and it will simultaneously remove the `.orig`.

You can combine the commands with `find` as follows:

```
find /example -name '*.orig' -exec rename . _1. {} +
find /example -name '*.orig' -exec rename .orig '' {} +
```

Or:

```
find /example -name '*.orig' -exec rename 's/(\..*)\.orig/_1$1/'
```

You don't even need `find` for this. If all your files are in the same directory, you can use the commands above directly, or, to make it recursive (assuming you are using bash):

```
shopt -s globstar                               ## make ** recurse into subdirectories
rename.ul . _1. **.orig && rename.ul .orig '' **.orig  ## util-linux
rename  's/(\..*)\.orig/_1$1/' **orig                  ## perl rename
```

In fact, strictly speaking, you don't even need `rename`. You can do everything in the shell (see [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for an explanation of the shell's string manipulation abilities):

```
for file in **/*.orig; do 
    newname="${file%%.*}_1.${file#*.}"
    mv "$file" "${newname/.orig/}"
done
```

---

Finally, a note on globs ([`-name` uses a glob, not a regular expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46444/22222)). The `*.*.orig` is Windows glob syntax for "anything ending in `.orig`". The equivalent and what you should use with your `find` is `*.orig`. The `*` alone matches anything, using `*.*.orig` will only match file names with two extensions, the last of which is `.orig`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should check what version of rename have installed in your system

```
readlink -e $(which rename)
```

So for `prename` (default in .deb hosts):

```
prename 's/(\.[^.]*)\.orig/_1$1/' *.*.orig
```

and for `rename.ul` from util-linux package

```
rename.ul \. _1\. *.*.orig     #add «_1» into file name
rename.ul \.orig '' *.*.orig   #remove «.orig» extention
```