# Search for files within a directory

Tags: find, osx, directory

I'm trying to search for all files given a certain string / regex value. So if I were to say search for all files that have "hello" in the name, how would I go about doing this? Ever more complex, how would I go about finding a file whose name begins with any two letters followed by a dash and then a number?

I've tried the find command and that has helped in the situation of hello. I would just type `find <dir> *hello*` but this doesn't work with the regex values.

If I type `find -E <dir> -regex '^[a-z]{2}-[1-9]'` nothing happens. Even if I type `find -E <dir> -regex '*[0-9]*'`, nothing happens.

Could someone help me with this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use `-regex` you'l have to operate `regular expression` but `pattern matching`. So `-regex '.*[0-9].*'`. Additionally note that `-regex` mean `-wholepath` so `.*/[a-z][a-z]-[1-9].*` would work.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I managed to get it to work by using the last command. Also, I believe the single quotation marks are important as well. Not using them doesn't output anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-regex` matches on the whole file path (not just the name), and is anchored by default (`^` and `$` implicit).

Here, you don't need regexps though, you can use the standard `-name` which takes a wildcard pattern and matches on the file name, not path:

```
find . -name '*hello*' -name '[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]-[1-9]*'
```

For file names that start with 2 letters, a hyphen and a digit from 1 to 9 and contain "hello".

With regexps, and here with FreeBSD/OS/X `find`, that would have to be:

```
find -E . -regex '.*hello[^/]*' -regex '.*/[[:alpha:]]{2}-[1-9][^/]*'
```

You need `[^/]*` instead of `.*` as otherwise, that would match on `./aa-9/hello/foo/bar` for instance.

In any case, `find <dir> *hello*` doesn't do what you think it does. The shell expands that `*hello*` glob to the list of non-hidden files or directories in the current directory whose name contains "hello" and passes the result as extra arguments to `find`.

Answer (score 2):

That fails because `*[0-9]*` is a [glob and not a regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46436/22222). In globs, `*` means "0 or more characters". However, in regular expressions, `*` means "0 or more of whatever is before the *". In other words, `*` is a *quantifier*
and is only relevant if it is quantifying something.

So, the regex that matches 0 or more characters, then 0 or more numbers is `.*[0-9]*`. Additionally, when using `-regex` with `find`, the regular expression is matched against the entire pat of the file, so you need to take that into account. Putting all this together, what you are looking for is:

```
find /path/to/dir -regex '.*/[a-z][a-z]-[1-9]‌​.*'
```

Finally, you must always quote such constructs when passing them to find. If you don't, the shell will expand them (so `*` becomes the list of all files and directories in your current directory) before passing them to `find`.