# Fetch all filenames with specific number of characters

Tags: regular-expression, mv, for

I want to change all filenames they have the exact length of 16 characters (digits and lower case letters). I tried `[0-9a-z]{16}` and `[0-9a-z]\{16\}` for the placeholder `regX` in the following snippet, but it doesn't work.

```
for file in <regX>
do
  mv "$file" "${file}.txt"
done
```

Comment: which shell are you using? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming) is different from regex

Comment: if you are using bash and has [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) , you can iterate over `for file in +([0-9a-z])` and then rename only if length of `${#file}` is 16

Comment: @Sundeep, my default shell `$ echo $0` is  `bash`. And it's not possible to specify the number of repetitions in this case?

Comment: You may find success with `????????????????` in place of `<regX>`, though this doesn't let you care what those sixteen characters are

Comment: What about using `find` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in +([0-9a-z])
do
    [[ ${#file} == 16 ]] && echo mv "$file" "${file}.txt"
done
```

- `+([0-9a-z])` means one or more of `[0-9a-z]` characters
- `${#file}` gives the length of filename
- `echo` is for dry run, remove once things are fine

Answer (score 5):

Shell globbing patterns [are not regular expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46436/22222). They may look similar, but they work quite differently in some respects.

The regular expression `[0-9a-z]{16}` matches a string that contains a run of 16 characters of the mentioned character range (the string containing the match may be longer).

The equivalent shell globbing pattern would be something like

```
*[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]*
```

This is because

1. Globbing patterns do not support modifiers that says "repeat the previous N times".
2. Globbing patterns are by default anchored to the beginning and end. This is why I inserted `*` at the start and end of the pattern. A `*` matches any number of any character. Remove these if you want to match *exactly* 16 characters.

You may create a string of 16 `[0-9a-z]` using Perl:

```
$ pattern="$( perl -e 'print "[0-9a-z]" x 16' )"
```

With `bash`, you may choose to iterate over all names in the current directory, and then test whether the names match your regular expression:

```
for name in *; do
    if [[ -f "$name" ]] && [[ "$name" =~ ^[0-9a-z]{16}$ ]]; then
        echo mv "$name" "$name.txt"
    fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you know that it's doing the right thing.

Notice that I've anchored the pattern so that longer names won't match. I'm also making sure, with the `-f` test, that the names that we get are actually those of regular files only.

Answer (score 3):

If you have perl-rename (called `rename` on Debian-based systems, `perl-rename` on others), you can do:

```
perl-rename -n 's/^[0-9a-z]{16}$/$&.txt/' *
```

If that does what you want, remove the `-n` to make it actually rename the files. The syntax of `perl-rename` is a perl command. Here, we're using the substitution operator (`s/from/to/`) which will replace `from` with `to`. The `from` in this case is your regex and the `to` is the special variable `$&` which means "whatever was matched", plus the extension `.txt`.

---

To do this with a shell glob (use [@Kusalananda's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/357911/22222) or [@Sundeep's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/357911/22222) approach, this is just for the sake of completion) :

```
for f in [0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]; do
    mv -- "$f" "$f".txt
done
```

---

With GNU `find`:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[0-9a-z]{16}' -exec mv {} {}".txt" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L16=$(csh -c 'repeat 16 echo -n "?"')
find . -name "$L16" ! -name '*[!0-9a-z]*' -exec sh -c '
   mv "$1" "$1.txt"
' {} {} \;
```