# regex with find command

Tags: files, find, regular-expression

Hello I want to find all files in a directory ending with .h  and I must use find command,I tried like this :

```
  find ~+ -name '\.h$'
```

strangely i have .h files but the command when executed doesn't produce output,so probably there is something wrong with the regex?

Comment: I you wanto to use a regex with GNU find: `find ~+ -regex ".*\.h"`

Answer (score 1):

The `-name` [takes a shell glob, not a regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46444/22222). You don't need to and shouldn't escape the `.`. Just use:

```
 find ~+ -name '*.h'
```

Comment: @IvanIvanov you're welcome. If one of these answers solved your problem, please accept it so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
 find /path/to/directory -name '*.h'
```