# Regex for checking only numbers are present after underscore not characters

Tags: shell, wildcards

I have if loop in my shell script which will check the is the table name is having any integer present this is the condition I am specifying:

```
if [[ "$able_name" == *[0-9]* ]]
```

Generally, the table name will be like this:

```
tablename_000
```

or

```
tablename_001
```

But I have a new file whose name is something like `table_V2`. Since the name matches the regex, it's entering this loop. How can I avoid this? It should enter the `if` loop only if integers are present after the underscore and not any other character.

Comment: Note that you are not actually using regular expressions here. That's a glob. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46436/22222) question for more details on the difference between the two.

Answer (score 5):

With standard `sh` syntax:

```
case ${table_name##*_} in
  ("$table_name" | "" | *[!0-9]*) echo >&2 incorrect;;
  (*) echo correct;;
esac
```

That is check that `$table_name` stripped of everything up to the right-most `_` in it is neither `$table_name` itself (which would mean `$table_name` had no `_`), nor the empty string, nor contained a non-digit character.

The standard command to match a string against a regexp is `expr` though it has a few issues and doesn't make for very legible code:

```
if expr " $table_name" : '.*_[0-9]\{1,\}$' > /dev/null; then
  echo Correct
else
  echo >&2 Incorrect
fi
```

The leading space is to avoid issues for values of `$table_name` like `+` or `--help`. regexps are anchored at the beginning implicitly (hence the `.*`) but not end (hence the `$`) and the result (0 or 1 here) is output on stdout in addition to being reflected in the exit status, hence the redirection to /dev/null.

Some `[` implementations like the `[` builtin of `zsh` and `yash` have a `=~` operator for that (using ERE, though you can change that to PCRE with `zsh`):

```
if [ "$table_name" '=~' '_[0-9]+$' ]; then
   echo Correct
else
   echo >&2 Incorrect
fi
```

`bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93` have a `=~` operator inside their `[[...]]` construct, though the syntax and the behaviour wrt quoting varies between implementations. Best is to use variables [as already shown by @BLayer](/a/397714)

`zsh -o extendedglob` and `ksh` (or `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob` that support a subset of `ksh` globs) have glob operators that are functionally equivalent to regexps albeit with a different syntax.

Translation RE -> ksh-glob / zsh-glob:

- `[0-9]` -> `[0-9]` / `[0-9]`
- `x+` -> `+(x)` / `x##`
- `$` or `^` -> implicit / implicit
- `.` -> `?`
- `.*` -> `*` (or `*(?)`) / `*` (or `?#`)

So in `ksh` (or `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob`):

```
case $table_name in
  (*_+([0-9]) echo correct;;
  (*) echo >&2 incorrect;;
esac
```

In `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
case $table_name in
  (*_[0-9]##) echo correct;;
  (*) echo >&2 incorrect;;
esac
```

`zsh` also has the `<x-y>` extended glob operator to match decimal numbers from `x` to `y` so you can also write it `(*_<->) echo correct`.

In those shells, those globs can also be used on the right hand side of the `=` aka `==` `[[...]]` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Many ways to do this. Here's a Bash version that goes the traditional regex way (or at least Bash's closest approximation to it):

```
pattern='^tablename_[[:digit:]]+$'
if [[ $filename =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo "Filename $filename is valid"
fi
```

A couple notes:

- For all but the simplest regular expressions it is advisable to use a variable as I've done here with `pattern`. Even though no word splitting or pathname expansion is applied to the expression inside `[[ ]]` there will be tilde, variable, and arithmetic expansion as well as process and command substitution. It's too easy to get incorrect or unexpected results with inline regex.
- I'm using POSIX character class `[:digit:]` but `0-9` is fine, too. I figured most of the other answers here would use the latter and it would be worthwhile to show the former for the sake of completeness

---

*Commentary: The fact that there are so many variations on this theme (in this thread alone) is one reason why some people don't like `sh`/`bash`...and why I love them.* :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most simple regex:

```
if [[ "$file" =~ _[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo OK $file
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Recommend using a regex option for this, but a normal glob for digits only could also be used. For example you could do something like

```
for file in tablename_[0-9]*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

Using the regex operator in `bash`, you could do something like,

```
for file in tablename_*; do
    if [[ $file =~ _([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `tablename_[0-9]*` matches on `tablename_1V` and `tablename_1_V1`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Absolutely! I did the glob and regex pattern solely on the OP's original examples. Assuming they don't have the names as you said