# grep: use square brackets to match specific characters

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression, quoting, wildcards

So I am experimenting with the power of grep using this [resources](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/)

The problem I am currently encountering is that it doesn't seem to work as I intended. so I have an demo.txt file that contains **foo.txt**, I use this code to search it:
`grep [a-z][a-z]o.txt demo.txt` but it returns empty. `zsh: no matches found: [a-z][a-z]o.txt` 
I wonder if my understanding of the use of square bracket is wrong?

here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: `setopt NO_NO_MATCH` in your `.zshrc`.  This is one of the most **annoying** defaults in zsh, for someone coming from bash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you aren't quoting the regular expression you want to pass to `grep`, it is being captured by the shell and the shell tries to expand it *before* calling `grep`. Now, the regular expression you have used happens to also be a valid shell glob pattern<sup>1</sup> which means "list all files or directories in the current folder whose name is any two characters, followed by the string `o.txt`". If your current directory contains any files or subdirectories matching that glob, then the glob will be expanded to the matching file names:

```
$ ls
abo.txt  demo.txt

$ cat demo.txt
foo.txt

$ set -x
$ grep [a-z][a-z]o.txt demo.txt 
+zsh:7> grep abo.txt demo.txt
```

The `set -x` tells `zsh` to show the actual commands it runs. As you can see, `[a-z][a-z]o.txt` is expanded to the matching file name: `abo.txt`, and *that* is what is passed to `grep`.

Now, you didn't actually have any matching file names in your directory, which means that `zsh` expanded the pattern to an empty string and didn't even launch `grep` at all. That's why the error is `zsh: no matches found: [a-z][a-z]o.txt`. That is zsh telling you that it failed to expand the glob to any matching files.

And, finally, this is what happens if you quote the pattern properly:

```
$ grep '[a-z][a-z]o.txt' demo.txt 
+zsh:12> grep '[a-z][a-z]o.txt' demo.txt
foo.txt
```

This time, the quotes protected the pattern from the shell, which passed it *as is* to `grep` and `grep` in turn interpreted it as a regular expression meaning "any two lower case letters, then an `o`, then *any other character*, and ending with `txt`". This is an important detail since `.` in a regular expression means "any character". So what you really wanted, was:

```
grep '[a-z][a-z]o\.txt' demo.txt
```

The `\.` "escapes" the `.` so that it only matches a literal dot and no longer means "any character". So, always quote your regular expressions and be careful with `.`!

Finally, here's an alternative way of writing this using extended regular expressions:

```
$ grep -E '[a-z]{2}o\.txt' demo.txt      
foo.txt
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>See [What is the definition of a regular expression?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46436/what-is-the-definition-of-a-regular-expression) for some more detail on globs vs regular expressions.</sub>