# Globbing Regex And Bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I just can't ever work out whether I am supposed to be using globbing or regex with bash.  My book on bash shell scripting is so confusing specifically because it doesn't clear this topic up and I never end up getting my understanding right.  Let me give an example, it states the following:... The . (dot) character means "any single character." Thus, a.c matches all of abc, aac, aqc, and so on.

Ok great, I'm thinking he's wrong because this is regex, but the first thing I do, is test it anyway:

```
$ touch abc aac aqc
$ ls
aac  abc  aqc
$ ls a.c
ls: cannot access 'a.c': No such file or directory
```

I then go and google globbing, and come across this post called "globbing tutorial", and I'm thinking, right this is the one.

https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial/

I'm almost immediately thinking it's all wrong because half his "globbing" is done via grep, which uses BRE which isn't globbing.  For example he states:

"$ is used to define the ending character"

This is wrong, because that's the regex meaning, and it's not globbing.  So I test it:

```
$ ls
aac  abc  aqc
$ ls c$
ls: cannot access 'c$': No such file or directory
```

So his number 1 hit link on google is wrong as well.  It's like there's no post that clarifies this topic either in books or online, so I need some help to define the difference between regex and globbing, with some absolute certainty.

Comment: Yeah that article appears to go completely off the rails partway through the `Caret – (^)` section. IMHO you'd be better off reading the bash manual's [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

Comment: As a general rule you never want the top hit, you want a respectable site. Preferably the manual, as steeldriver suggested, but certainly not whatever random website google decides to show you. That said, does this answer you? [What is the definition of a regular expression?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46436) It might be a duplicate, if it answers you to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 4):

The only place where `bash` uses regexps is with the `=~` operator of its `[[ ... ]]` construct, and it's POSIX extended regexps in that case:

```
if [[ abc =~ ^a.b$ ]]; then
  echo 'abc matches the ^a.b$ ERE'
fi
```

Everywhere else:

- `case abc in (a?b) echo 'abc matches the a?b glob pattern'; esac`
- `[[ abc = a?b ]] &&  echo 'abc matches the a?b glob pattern'`
- `printf '%s\n' a?b`: actual globbing aka filename generation aka pathname expansion
- `printf '%s\n' "${var#a?b}" "${var%a?b}" "${var##a?b}" "${var%%a?b}" "${var/a?b/x}`
- `compgen -G 'a?b'` (same with `complete`).
- `help 'r??d'`

That's shell wildcards aka glob patterns aka filename / fnmatch patterns.

Run `info bash pattern` to learn about those in bash specifically. `info -n conditional bash` will get you to the *Conditional construct* section inside which you'll find the description of `[[ ... ]]` and its `=~` operator.

Other tools like `grep`, `find`, `vim`, `perl`, `firefox` can use either or both in varying contexts. Their documentation will tell you. Also beware, there are many flavours of both types of patterns. As a rule of thumb, glob patterns are typically used for matching filenames (like in shell globs or `find`'s `-name`/`-path`) and regexp for arbitrary text matching.

ksh93 is a shell that can use regexps (basic, extended, perl-like or augmented) in its globs:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ~(E:^a.b$)
a=b
axb
```

In zsh, you can use regexps (extended or pcre) in its globs via the `e` glob qualifier:

```
$ printf '%s\n' *(e['[[ $REPLY =~ "^a.b$" ]]'])
a=b
axb
```

```
$ zmodload zsh/pcre
$ printf '%s\n' *(e['[[ $REPLY -pcre-match "^a.b\z" ]]'])
a=b
axb
```

(where `\z` being the PCRE equivalent of ERE `$` as in PCRE `$` matches at the end of the subject *but also before a newline at the end of subject*).

If you set the `rematchpcre` option (`set -o rematchpcre`), `[[ =~ ]]` uses PCRE instead of ERE there.